# How to print with custom page in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can i print a lot of same barcode image (depends on total barcode) in rails?
Example total_barcode is 6, so i print 6 same barcode.

The image will fit with the layout.

If the size of paper only fit 4 image, and it will generate another page until there are 6 image

Its looks like

XX(page 1)
XX(page 1)
XX(page 2) the x is image

Thanks i hope you guys can understand what i'm trying to say

Comment: It feels to me like you are asking about how to add pagination to your application. I suggest having a look at gems like [`pagy`](https://github.com/ddnexus/pagy#-its-easy-to-use-and-customize).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

I would suggest first creating the barcodes page as html, and then converting to pdf.

To create the barcodes on an html page, you have to use a barcode font (Google it), you will need to load the fonts into the page, and specify the barcode font for the barcode "text" in css. When you render text with a barcode font, it appears on the page as a barcode.

Next you need to convert the html to pdf. I suggest using the same url, but appending .pdf to the url instead of .html. You can look for libraries that convert from html to pdf.

Sorry I haven't provided much detail, this is a big project!